# CANoe tool DBC configuration

Tags: canoe

I have been trying to create a DBC file in CANoe, but in the latest demo version 13.0 I am not getting any option for environment variables.

Can anyone please help me finding or guiding me to how to get the environment variables in the DBC file?

Answer (score 2):

Many pages of the help are referring to env vars being usable only if they were added to the Database, but then again via the CANoe Ribbon there is no way of adding new Environment Variables, and this is were you are confused.

To set new Environment Variables, you'll need CANdb++. To see existing Environment Variables, go `View > List > Environment Variables`. From here, you can add new env vars to the database.

Env Vars are typically used as interface between network nodes and specifically in panels as handles.

Demo versions of CANoe might lack certain functionalities, but luckily the CANdb++ editor is a free tool you can [download from vector](https://www.vector.com/mx/es/download/?tx_vectorproducts_productdownloaddetail%5Bdownload%5D=46267&tx_vectorproducts_productdownloaddetail%5Baction%5D=show&tx_vectorproducts_productdownloaddetail%5Bcontroller%5D=Productdownload&cHash=57c1a26c33b686432237ec2f34831575)

---

<sub>**disclaimer**: this answer is based on [this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62912437/2125110).</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are creating a new DBC probably for learning purpose. An important point to be noted here is CANoe will stop supporting Environment Variables in the future versions. The current comment from Vector (according to v13.0 help document) is this:

> The creation of environment variables is no longer supported. Instead, use system variables directly in CANoe. Currently CANoe still supports the use of environment variables. This support will not be available in future versions.

So, it is preferred to use system variables rather than environment variables.
To view the above comment in the v13.0 help document, go to the index tab and type "Environment Variable".

Answer (score 0):

The creation of environment variables is no longer supported. Instead, use system variables directly in CANoe. Currently CANoe still supports the use of environment variables. This support will not be available in future versions.